# upload and post a file from client (react js) to nodejs express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload

From my client side I have this code, in react js componet I create this:

```
class PopinForm extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      file : {},
      isError : {
        file : false,
      }
    };
  }


  //upload here
  _handleUploadFile = () => {
    uploadFile(this.state.file)
  };

  render() {
    <Root>
      <Input width="45%" type="file" onChange={ (e) => this.setState({file: e.target.files[0]}) } />
      <ButtonPopin width="20%" onClick={this._handleUploadFile}>
        Upload
      </ButtonPopin>
    </Root>
}
export default translate('translations')(PopinForm);
```

Then in my export module, this the function `uploadFile`:

```
export function uploadFile(file) {
  fetch(`${apiUrl}/upload`, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: headers,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    body: file,
  })
    .then(request => request.post())
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`>>>>>>> an internal error occurred: ${JSON.stringify(err, null, 3)}`)
    })
}
```

Using reactjs, I recover my file data from an input type file. This is my file when I made a `console.log(file)` :

> File
>   lastModified: 1522422082000   ​
>   lastModifiedDate: Date
>   2018-03-30T15:01:22.000Z
>   ​name: "test.xls"   ​
>   size: 7105   ​
>   type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" ​ 
>   webkitRelativePath: ""

So it matches well with the right file I upload from the input type file.

But, on my server side I'am using multer and this is the method I use to recover the file, here the code in `index.js`:

```
// instantiate multer storage to define the tmp folder path to store file
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'tmp/')
  },
  // register the file with his original name and extension
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  },
})
// declare the upload method with storage path and filename registration
const upload = multer({storage: storage})

//  upload XLSX massive request import
app.post('/upload', upload.single('uploadRequests'), require(path.join(__dirname, 'some', 'path', 'to', 'uploadRequest.js')))
```

WHen I submit the upload file I have this error: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 12): TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined** due to the request I made in the file uploadRequests.js here: `const fileName = req.file.originalname`

This is the code for `uploadRequests.js`:

```
const uploadRequests = async (req, res) => {
  // get filename by req
  const fileName = req.file.originalname
  // instantiate excel class
  const workbook = new Excel.Workbook()

  workbook.xlsx.readFile(req.file.path)
    .then(async () => {
      // treatment on xlsx file test with postman exmaple and files, nothing went wrong here
      // fetch on database request and CRUD method to update or create data
      return res.json({message: 'massive import request success !', data: data})
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error(`workbook readFile method return an ${err}`)
    })
}
module.exports = uploadRequests
```

I am new to nodejs, and I would like to know how properly recover my file from the client side on my nodejs server.

Comment: please can you update the question with your code from uploadRequests.js?

Comment: @Olivier Wilkinson I have updated my post, but just you to know, my uploadRequest method is just a treatment to read file, the problem I have for the moment is only to recover my file send from my client side.
Thank you for your answer by the way.

Comment: How do you create your FormData?

Comment: @devserkan check my update, I write the code from react component to better unerstand how I get my file

Comment: No pro here but I know Multer expects a multipart/form-data and name in the FormData must be the same as what multer upload route expects. `const data = new FormData()` and `data.append("uploadRequests", e.target.files[ 0 ]` or how you handle the file in the state. Right now can you see files in tmp directory when you try to upload anything?